# Switch from i3 to i3-gaps - cannot launch i3-gaps

Tags: 18.04, window-manager, 18.10, i3-wm, tiling

I use Ubuntu 18.10. I installed i3 before, but I wanted i3-gaps now. So I uninstalled it.

```
sudo apt purge i3*
sudo apt autoremove
```

This however did not remove the i3 option from the login screen (the gear button next to the login button, it has `Ubuntu`, `Ubuntu on Wayland`, `i3` and `i3-debug` options).

I than followed [this article](https://benjames.io/2017/09/03/installing-i3-gaps-on-ubuntu-16-04/) about installing i3-wm at Ubuntu 16.04. It should work, the only problem I had was that I had to create `~/.i3` directory manually, it was not created after install.

But nothing changed on the login screen - there is no new `i3-gaps` (or whatever should it be) option. When I select the `i3` option, the i3 bar is empty with error message (*Error: status_command not found or is missing a library dependency (exit 127)*) and half of the features doesn't work - for example I cannot launch the d-menu (mod+d). When I open multiple terminals, there are exactly next to each other (as in i3) without gaps.

Directly after install I made `~/.i3` directory, copied there global config and added following lines:

```
for_window [class="^.*"] border pixel 0

gaps inner 30
gaps outer 20
```

Edit: Could it be possible that i3-gaps is installed, but just doesn't work, like missing some dependencies? Because adding `exec i3` into ~/.xinitrc and running `startx` from TTY does the same as logging into i3 from login screen. So I think that either i3 somehow survived or i3-gaps didn't really install correctly. If that's the case, almost nothing is installed and it doesn't even read my config file (`~/.i3/config`). Any ideas?

Edit 2: New config location solved it, thanks @nephilim ! The correct config location is `.config/i3/config`. The dependency problems were solved by installing some i3 packages, such as `i3status`.

Comment: Are you moving from Manjaro? The config location should be ~/.config/i3/config

Comment: No, Ubuntu. But that .config location solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong config location.

The correct location is :

> $HOME/.config/i3/config  or ~/.config/i3/config

not

> $HOME/.i3/config or ~/.i3/config

That is something that's mostly only used in the Manjaro i3 ISO.

Missing bar is due to missing dependencies such as i3-status. Check through your config and see which one is used there(might also be i3-blocks).

I'm writing this as an answer, so people that stumble upon this page can easily find the answer. Many tend to skip "unanswered" questions.